# Get distinct substring in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query that returns the following result.

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Path from MyTable;
```

**Result**

```
+-------------------------+
|        Path             |
+-------------------------+
| home/MYPATH1/xxx/yyy    |
| home2/MYPATH2/xxxx/yyyy |
+-------------------------+
```

and so on..

I want to extract just the second term of the path returned. 

i.e `MYPATH1` and `MYPATH2`.

Can anyone tell me how to do it? Thanks and Regards.

Comment: I am a newbie. I tried using substring(instr ()) but didnt work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can achieve this with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.

[Read here to know more about SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

**Query**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX
(
   SUBSTRING_INDEX
  (
    `path`,'/',2
  ),'/',-1
)AS `path`  
FROM myTable;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cca8d/5)

Comment: Hi why do I get an error if i add the keyword "distinct" before the substring_index on this query?

Comment: I guess distinct doesnt work on views. It hangs if I add the keyword distinct

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `substring_index()` for this.

```
mysql> select substring_index(substring_index('home/MYPATH1/xxx/yyy','/',2),'/',-1) as path;
+---------+
| path    |
+---------+
| MYPATH1 |
+---------+

mysql> select substring_index(substring_index('home2/MYPATH2/xxxx/yyyy','/',2),'/',-1) as path;
+---------+
| path    |
+---------+
| MYPATH2 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Same answer as Ullas's. Eventhough you answered first, I think, lack of readability is why u didn't get an upvote. Make it a little more readable and simpler.